# os.popen return empty after a certain time

Tags: python, operating-system, openwrt

I have a function in my project which returns me the /tmp partition size and how much is available and it works well for sometimes, but after a certain time the os.popen function returns empty file object and the function will throw error. the following is my code.

```
def get_temp_dir_size():
    """ the function returns the tmp partetion size and avilable size"""
    data = [0,0]
    with os.popen('df -h /tmp') as f:
        f_data = f.readlines()
        try:
            data = re.findall(r'(\d*\.*\d+)M',f_data[-1])
        except:
            log.exception("*** Some error occured")
            log.debug("*** data in the file : {0}".format(f_data))
    return {'flashSize':data[0],'flashFree':data[1]}
```

the following is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/dnp/dnp_utils.py", line 614, in get_temp_dir_size
    data = re.findall(r'(\d*\.*\d+)M',f_data[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
2018-02-15 05:51:36,626 [DEBUG](           dnp_utils: 617): *** data in the file : []
```

Comment: The system is stuck because it doesn't need that file. Play with your own files, not system files.

Comment: What is your OS and what is the device on which you have /tmp? (I guess it's some sort of flash memory?) Can you reproduce this behavior by simply calling df -h /tmp?

Comment: @dsgdfg: Yes it stucks, none of the file read operation is happening, but still i need the information that I can get only from system commands.

Comment: @DyZ: operating system is openwrt,yes it is a flash memory. it is giving the output when I am executing in the shell, feels like some kind of memory issue, but not able to trace it.

Comment: If you need to write a service, you need to copy it to another file at a time when the file is seen continuously. You can find information about these operations in system logs(`tail -f /var/log/syslog`).